# Context is always empty in Apollo Meteor Integration when using IE11 on production

Tags: meteor, graphql, apollo

The context object is always empty when the browser is IE11

```
Mutation: {
    insertBusinessIdea (_, {name}, context) {

      if (!context.userId) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('User must be logged in to create a new Business Idea')
      } // IE11 not working
}
```

It happens only when deployed in production and only using IE11. On localhost:3000 it works just fine, even using IE11

It might be worth saying that on production it's deployed as a docker container behind an nginx reverse proxy.